# Any idea why protractor is getting installed in a different directory on mac m1 even after giving permission to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: javascript, macos, installation, protractor

**First error**
user@suser-Air / % npm install -g protractor

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules

**Solution** - I gave permission to the above path and ran again npm install -g protractor

**Second error**

user@suser-Air  / % npm install -g protractor

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor

npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/protractor

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor' -> '/usr/local/bin/protractor'

npm ERR! [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor' -> '/usr/local/bin/protractor'] {

npm ERR! cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor' -> '/usr/local/bin/protractor'] {

- Node Version: `14.16.1`
- NPM version : '6.14.12'
- Operating System and Version `macOS Big Sur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run the command in [sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611671/9150146) mode

```
sudo npm install -g protractor
```

Comment: Thank you, above command successfully installed protractor in path "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor"